# Acora doesn't work with gzip-opened files

Tags: python, parsing, gzip

I'm trying to run Acora parsing on a file, which works as expected on plain text files.  When I try to run it on gzipped files using the python gzip module (which is supposed to allow transparent reading of compressed files) I receive nothing in return.  This is not a case of not rewinding the file to the beginning, I tried it from fresh with both compressed and uncompressed.

```
from acora import AcoraBuilder

f1 = open('input_file.txt', 'r')
ac = AcoraBuilder(tokens).build()
ac.filefindall(f1)  ## Works as expected

import gzip
f2 = gzip.open('input_file.txt.gz', 'r')
ac = AcoraBuilder(tokens).build()
ac.filefindall(f2)  ## Doesn't work, returns no results
```

Please let me know if this is something I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

I think Acora doesn't has support to compacted files. You need to extract it before use it.

```
from acora import AcoraBuilder
import gzip

with gzip.GzipFile('input_file.txt.gz', 'rb') as fp:
    f2 = fp.read()

ac = AcoraBuilder(tokens).build()
ac.findall(f2)
```

Anyway, acora has native support to search in files.

```
keywords = ['Import', 'FAQ', 'Acora', 'NotHere'.upper()]

builder = AcoraBuilder([s.encode('ascii') for s in keywords])
ac = builder.build()

found = set(kw for kw, pos in ac.filefind('README.rst'))
```

Comment: As I understand, Acora does files by doing chunked reads using f.read(), which gzip should handle transparently. But it doesn't. I'm specifically trying to avoid unzipping it and loading the entire file into memory.